# openshift start build forbidden

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am trying to create a build and deployment pipeline in OpenShift via Jenkins. I have followed their official tutorial: https://github.com/OpenShiftDemos/openshift-cd-demo
and properly set all policies ( i am using different project names and application but the same strategy ) yet the Jenkins app deployed on cicd project cant start to build in dev project.

**Error**:

> Error from server (Forbidden): buildconfigs.build.openshift.io buildconfig not found though the build is created and can be seen via the web console.

I am using the `--from-file` instead of `--from-dir` for binary input. 
Please help if any other policies need to be set for the Jenkins service account in cicd project to "start-build" in dev project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Jenkins need to have access to dev project, you can use the following command to give access:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:serviceaccount:cicd-tools:jenkins -n example-openshift-dockerfile
```

cicd-tools: Project jenkins is installed in

example-openshift-dockerfile: Project that will be changed by Jenkins